# mybatis callable statement out parameter integer

Tags: java, integer, mybatis, callable

I am under making one stored procedure in Oralce 11g and I should call this from mybatis mapper. The procedure takes three parameters and the third is for OUT paramter. I coded like below, but the OUT parameter was returned as 0 in Java.

mybatis mapper:

```
<mapper namespace="...">
<select id="setUserRole" statementType="CALLABLE" parameterType="hashmap">
    { call set_user_role(#{email}, #{roleName}, #{cntPrivs, mode=OUT, jdbcType=NUMERIC})}
</select>
</mapper>
```

mybatis Mapper interface:

```
public interface UserMapper {
    void setUserRole(Map<String, Object> map);
}
```

service layer utilizing mybatis mapper:

```
@Override
public boolean setBasicRole(String email) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Integer privilegesCount = 0;
    map.put("roleName", UserServiceImpl.ROLE_BASIC);
    map.put("email", (Object)email);
    map.put("cntPrivs", privilegesCount);
    userMapper.setUserRole(map);

    System.out.println("cntPrivs : " + privilegesCount); // printed zero

    return (privilegesCount > 0)? true : false;
}
```

in Oracle code:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
    cnt_privs number := 0;
begin
    set_user_role('<set my email>', 'NORMAL', cnt_privs);
    dbms_output.put_line(cnt_privs); // printed more than 0
end;
/
```

I checked OUT paramter of the procedure returns more than 0 in database area.
In Java, "privilegeCount" variable should be more than 0 after calling userMapper.setUserRole() method. but returns 0.

When I initialized "privilegeCount" as 10, it stayed 10 after calling userMapper.setUserRole().

It seems like "privilegeCount" does not get synchronized with mybatis.

How do I deal with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

after calling mybatis mapper method, i could get OUT parameter by:

```
(Integer)map.get("cntPrivs")
```

I checked the log.

> INFO : jdbc.audit - 4. CallableStatement.getInt(3) returned 1

the third OUT parameter was returned normally.
(given role has just one permission )